# macro to make the cells value zero after filtering

Tags: excel, vba

Requrirement:i am filter the row which is J6 to negative value after filtering the row there will multiple row displayed i need make all the row zero

[image: the data after filtering]

solution : i need make all the rows to zero or Make the values as Null “0” after filtering

Comment: All **the rows**, I mean entire rows, or all the visible cells in column "J:J"?

Comment: After filtering only visible cells I have to make zero which is j:j olny @faneDuru

Comment: Please, test the code I posted. It will make 0 all the visible cells **in column "J:J"**.

Comment: I thought that the header is on the first row. I will adapt the code to make 0 starting from J7, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next code. It will process column "J:J" **after filtering**, and make 0 all the visible cells in this column:

```
Sub makeAllRowsZero()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, rngVs As Range
   
   Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the necessary sheet
   lastR = sh.Range("J" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
   On Error Resume Next 'for the case of no any visible cell...
    Set rngVs = sh.Range("J7:J" & lastR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
   On Error GoTo 0
   If Not rngVs Is Nothing Then
        rngVs.Value = 0
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: zero it correct but its making the header which is j6 also zero

Comment: bro just wanted to know the code that after filtering at j6 is header to get next cell row number so that i can pass

Comment: @Harsha R  Please, try the updated code. It will start placing 0 after the seventh row.

Comment: hey  Fane Duru could you please explain the above code

Comment: @FaneDuru no need to use `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`. You can do `Range("J7:J" & lastR) = 0`  - it will not affect the cells that are hidden under the filter

Comment: @FaneDuru can yo explain me the above code  On Error Resume Next 'for the case of no any visible cell...
    Set rngVs = sh.Range("J7:J" & lastR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
   On Error GoTo 0
   If Not rngVs Is Nothing Then
        rngVs.Value = 0
   End If

Comment: @Harsha R I tried commenting the first line. If there will not be any visible cell in the respective area, trying to create a range will raise an error. Then the code checks if the range has been created using: `If Not rngVs Is Nothing Then`.